# How to ensure that the package is available in the future?

Tags: apt

I need to install a fixed version package.

```
apt-get install virtualbox-dkms=6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.2

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.2' for 'virtualbox-dkms' was not found
```

After some time most of the old package versions are removed (as it happened with the `6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.2` version). How to tell which versions will remain in the repository and which will be removed? Is there a repository where all versions are kept?

Comment: For the sake of clarity, I removed `-qq`

Comment: ALL older versions will eventually be superseded by newer versions and removed from the Ubuntu repositories. Your example `virtualbox-dkms=6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04`  seems a fairly old version that was apparently superseded due to published vulnerabilities (CVEs). Are you SURE you want to use an insecure version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot ensure that. The Ubuntu developpers packages the software, and decide what version is available.

The repository where it is kept, is the software repository of your current Ubuntu version. Commonly, but not guaranteed, an older version will be kept, even if it is superseded by a newer version. Then indeed, you can "pin" that older version so it is excluded from updating.

However, do not expect the package to be available with a newer Ubuntu distribution. You could archive the `.deb` installation file of the package yourself, and try reinstalling it on a newer system. At that point, it becomes unsupported software. Installing it sometimes may work, but many other times will not work anymore, because dependencies are not anymore satisfied. It is also not recommended. even if this old version does install, stability with the newer system is not guaranteed. And what is worse, there may be significant security vulnerabilities in an older package that are discovered and fixed in newer versions.